# Surprising behaviour related to records, protocols and compilation

Tags: clojure

I encountered a, to me, slightly surprising behaviour seemingly
related to clojure records.

The setup is as follows:

1. One namespace defines a record type:

   ```
   (ns defrecordissue.arecord)

   (defrecord ARecord [])
   ```
2. Another namespace defines a protocol, and extends it to the record
   type defined in 1:

   ```
   (ns defrecordissue.aprotocol
     (:require [defrecordissue.arecord])
     (:import [defrecordissue.arecord ARecord]))

   (defprotocol AProtocol
     (afn [this]))

   (extend-protocol AProtocol
     ARecord
     (afn [this] 42))
   ```
3. A third namespace constructs an instance of the record and invokes
   the protocol function on the record.

   ```
   (ns defrecordissue.aot1
     (:require [defrecordissue.aprotocol]
               [defrecordissue.arecord]))

   (defrecordissue.aprotocol/afn (defrecordissue.arecord/->ARecord))
   ```

When the defrecordissue.aot1 namespace is compiled, in my case using
`lein compile defrecordissue.aot1`, compilation fails with the
following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :afn of protocol: #'defrecordissue.aprotocol/AProtocol found for class: defrecordissue.arecord.ARecord, compiling:(aot1.clj:5:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3463)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7153)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7219)
    at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:438)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$compile$fn__5023.invoke(core.clj:5541)
    at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5540)
    at user$eval7.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6609)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6582)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2852)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:308)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:327)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:362)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :afn of protocol: #'defrecordissue.aprotocol/AProtocol found for class: defrecordissue.arecord.ARecord
    at clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn.invoke(core_deftype.clj:541)
    at defrecordissue.aprotocol$fn__40$G__35__45.invoke(aprotocol.clj:5)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3458)
    ... 25 more
```

If I change 3) to construct the record class directly, like so:

```
(ns defrecordissue.aot2
  (:require [defrecordissue.aprotocol]
            [defrecordissue.arecord]))

(defrecordissue.aprotocol/afn (defrecordissue.arecord.ARecord.))
```

Compilation succeeds.

My suspicion is that this is somehow related to
http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-371, but I don't understand
exactly what is happening.

I should also add that without the `lein clean`, compilation succeeds
the second time, since a class for the record is now available on the
classpath. Therefore, I can get around this problem by AOT-compiling
the namespace defining the record type.

I created a simple leiningen project on GitHub that illustrates the
issue, see README for usage:
https://github.com/ragnard/defrecordissue

Why am I seeing this behaviour, and what is the correct way to avoid it?

**UPDATE**

I added a new branch to the GitHub repo better illustrating the core issue:
https://github.com/ragnard/defrecordissue/tree/more-realistic/

The problem occurs regardless of where (ie. in which namespace) the record 
instance is constructed.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the problem with your repo. Here's three solutions which work for me:

1. Tell `lein compile` to compile more namespaces:

   ```
   lein compile defrecordissue.aprotocol defrecordissue.arecord defrecordissue.aot1
   ```
2. Put

   ```
   :aot [defrecordissue.aprotocol defrecordissue.arecord defrecordissue.aot1]
   ```

   in `project.clj`.
3. Put

   ```
   :aot :all
   ```

   in `project.clj`.

The latter two make `lein compile` do the work of `lein aot1` (in the case of 2.) and both `lein aot1` and `lein aot2` (in the case of 3.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I can get around the issue by AOT
compiling the `defrecordissue.arecord` namespace. However, this is not
entirely satisfactory in the case where the problem originated. In
that case, both `defrecordissue.arecord` and
`defrecordissue.aprotocol` are part of a library and
`defrecordissue.aot1` is just a consumer of that library, and doesn't
know about the record type (or even the protocol). It does not
instantiate the record types directly, as in this contrived example.
I'd like to deliver the library without any AOT compiled classes if
possible.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this all the time. This is what I've come up with and it seems to work:

```
(defmacro with-datatype
  [datatype & body]
  (let [last-dot (.lastIndexOf ^String (str datatype) ".")
        ns (-> datatype
               str
               (subs 0 last-dot)
               symbol)]
     `(do
        (require (quote ~ns))
        (import ~datatype)
        ~@body)))

(defmacro extend-type*
  [datatype & extensions]
  `(with-datatype ~datatype
     (extend-type ~datatype
       ~@extensions)))

(defmacro extend-protocol*
  [protocol & specs]
  (let [splitter (let [l (atom nil)]
                   #(if (symbol? %) (reset! l %) @l))
        specs (partition-by splitter specs)]
    `(do
       ~@(for [[datatype & extensions] specs]
           `(extend-type* ~datatype ~protocol ~@extensions)))))
```

Then you only need to change your second code block to:

```
(ns defrecordissue.aprotocol)

(defprotocol AProtocol
  (afn [this]))

(extend-protocol* AProtocol
  defrecordissue.arecord.ARecord
  (afn [this] 42))
```

Maybe not the cleanest solution, but you don't have to AOT your libraries any more.